# How would one save the state of button.isEnabled = false?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have to save the state of a button as to when the app quits and launches again, the button will still remain disabled.

`button.isEnabled = false`

What will be the best way to save the state of the button?

Comment: Answer for your question is UserDefaults https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
// inside viewDidLoad 

button.isEnabled =  !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "buttonDisabled")
```

the default value for key `buttonDisabled` is `false`  , change it like this

```
// inside action

UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "buttonDisabled")
```

to disable the button

Comment: When app quits and launches again, button becomes active again.Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Once button is disabled, how do I get it enabled again? `UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "buttonDisabled")`?

Comment: Just another question, what is "buttonDisabled" referring to? The reason for my question is that I want to save the state of two buttons inside one function.

Comment: buttonDisabled is a key that either has a true/false value , it can be any characters you want for another button you can save an array instead of bool in defaults with `UserDefaults.standard.set([true,false],"somekey")` sure it needs another handling for reading

Answer (score 1):

This is what `UserDefaults` is for:

```
// Store
UserDefaults.standard.set(state, forKey: "buttonState") // 'state' here is the current button state

// Retrieve
button.isEnabled = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "buttonState")

// Register a default value (this will be used if no value is stored)
// Can be safely called on each launch
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["buttonState" : false]) // or whatever default should be
```